# Infinite simple group of exponent a power of 2

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let G be a simple group of exponent 2^n for n>1. Is G necessarily finite? If not, what is an example of an infinite simple group of exponent a power of 2?

Comment: No (for $n$ large enough). For $n$ large enough it's known that the free Burnside group $B(2,2^n)$ is infinite, and also known that it's virtually aperiodic. (I call a group aperiodic if its only finite quotient is $\{1\}$). This finite index aperiodic subgroup being finitely generated and nontrivial, it has a simple quotient, necessarily infinite.

Answer (score 6):

> For every large enough $n$, there exist infinite simple groups of exponent dividing $n$.

(I call a group aperiodic if it has no nontrivial finite quotient.) Indeed, by the solution to the restricted Burnside problem the Burnside group $B(2,n)$ is known to be virtually aperiodic; let $B(2,n)^\circ$ be its (unique) minimal finite index subgroup, it is thus finitely generated. For $n$ large enough, $B(2,n)$ is known to be infinite. Hence $B(2,n)^\circ$ is infinite too, hence has a simple quotient, also aperiodic and hence infinite. $\Box$

The above proof produces groups of exponents dividing $n$, probably with some more efforts we can get exponent exactly $n$ but I think it's unimportant. I don't know if one can obtain quasi-finite groups in this context, when the exponent is $2^m$ (quasi-finite means infinite with all proper subgroups finite); these are close variants of Tarski monsters. Also probably one can produce infinitely generated countable examples, and uncountable too, but this requires other/additional arguments. Nevertheless:

> $\forall n$, there exists **no** infinite locally finite simple group of exponent $n$. (Nor even in which every element has order dividing some power of $n$.)

For $n=2^k$ (or more generally $p^aq^b$ with $p,q$ prime, these would be locally solvable and indeed Malcev proved that there is no infinite, locally solvable simple group. In general, this is essentially due to Hartley (1995) [(Springerlink behind paywall)](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-011-0329-9_1). Namely he proved that for every finite subset $F$ in a simple locally finite group $G$, there exists a finite subgroup $H$ containing $F$, and a normal subgroup $N$ of $H$ such that $H/N$ is simple and $F$ projects injectively into $H/N$. Since (by classification) finite simple groups of given exponent have bounded order, this implies the result. (Hartley also quotes Meierfrankelfeld for the same result.) The statement is explicit in a 2005 paper by Cutolo-Smith-Wiegold ([ScienceDirect](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869305001420)), Lemma 4.

Comment: To finite group theorists "$X$ is involved in $Y$", usually means$Y$ has subgroups $A,B$ with $B \lhd A$ such that $A/B \cong X$" (probably what you mean by "$X$ is a subquotient of $Y$"). . Hartley wasn't exclusively a finite group theorist, but I knew him, and I think he would have used "involved" in that sense.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So for sure I can find an infinite simple groups with exponent a power of 2, as the simple factor of the Burnside group B(2,2^m) for m large enough, right? Do you have any good reference for this? Thanks again.

Comment: @marcos you missed the point: a priori these simple quotients of $B(2,2^m)$ might be finite. I pass to the aperiodic finite index subgroup and then take a simple quotient and then I'm sure that the quotient is infinite. The cost is that the number of generators is not $2$. Probably it's true that $B(2,2^m)$ has infinite simple quotients too, but would require a further argument.

Comment: I see, so I need to consider the aperiodic finite index subgroup to conclude. Is there any reference where I can find all of it? Thanks.