# Locally finite groups with finite exponent

Tags: gr.group-theory

I am interested in infinite groups that are locally finite (finitely-generated subgroups are finite) with finite exponent (there exists integer $m$ such that $g^{m}=1$ for every element $g$).

I can think of only one method for constructing examples: an infinite direct product $G = \prod_{i\in I} H_{i}$, where $I$ is an infinite index set, and each $H_{i}$ is a finite group of size at most $n$ (for some $n$).

Question 1: Are there other methods for constructing infinite locally finite groups of finite exponent?

Question 2: Are there infinite locally finite groups of finite exponent that are not direct products?

Question 3: Are there infinite locally finite groups of finite exponent that are simple?

Comment: I believe that Tarski monsters are not locally finite, and that in fact any Tarski monster can be generated by two elements.

Comment: Ah, of course not, you're right.

Comment: You have subgroups of these direct products. "Not direct products": do you mean directly indecomposable?

Comment: Q3: No There's no such locally finite group (the argument appeared recently on the site, I'll look for it)

Comment: @YCor Yes, thanks, I would be interested in an example that is directly indecomposable.

Comment: Q3: by Hartley/ Meierfrankenfeld, every simple locally finite group has "a Kegel cover", i.e., for every finite subset $F$ there exists subgroups $G,N$ with $N$ normal in $G$ and $F\subset G$, such that the quotient $G/N$ is finite simple and $F$ is mapped injectively into $G/N$. By classification, simple groups of exponent $\le k$ have bounded cardinal, say $\le n_k$. Taking $F$ of cardinal $>n_k$ yields a contradiction.

Comment: A directly indecomposable such group is quite immediate: take $C_2$ cyclic of order $2$, $V$ to be an infinite abelian group of exponent $3$, and $G$ the semidirect product $C_2\ltimes_{\pm}V$. This is not very mysterious and just an instance of my previous comment: "you also have subgroups of these direct products": here this is a subgroup of some power of $\mathrm{Sym}(3)=D_6$.

Comment: Jeremy Rickard has found the recent post, about the non-existence of infinite simple locally finite groups of finite exponent: https://mathoverflow.net/a/352400/14094. This makes Q3 a duplicate (and Q2 is too immediate to deserve an answer). You might ask whether every locally finite group of finite exponent is isomorphic to a subgroup of a direct product of finite groups with bounded exponent.

Comment: About Q1 - you can use the wreath products. Most of them are not even residually finite. In general, any extension of a  locally finite  group by a locally finite  group is locally finite. And an extension of a group of exponent $m$ by a group of exponent $n$ has exponent dividing $mn$.

Comment: @YCor Suppose I define $G$ to be the union $B_{0}(1,n)\cup B_{0}(2,n)\cup B_{0}(3,n)\cup\cdots$. Then $G$ is countably infinite, locally finite, and it has bounded exponent. Could it be the case that $G$ is a subgroup of a direct product of finite groups, or is this a counterexample?

(By $B(m,n)$ I mean the free Burnside group with $m$ generators and exponent $n$. Also $B_{0}(m,n)$ is $B(m,n)/N$ where $N$ is the intersection of all subgroups with finite index in $B(m,n)$. By the solution to the restricted Burnside problem, $B_{0}(m,n)$ is finite.)

Comment: @DillonM This group, let's call it $B_0(\omega,n)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of a direct (unrestricted) product of finite groups (that is, is residually finite). Indeed if $w\neq 1$ belongs to it, say it belongs to $B_0(k,n)$ for some $k$. Since $B_0(k,n)$ is a retract of $B_0(\omega,n)$, $w$ survives in the finite quotient $B_0(k,n)$.